# Magento2 System Requirements PHP Memory Limit

Tags: magento2, server-setup, memory

What are the system requirements of Magento 2 regarding PHP memory limit ([Resource Limits: `memory_limit`](http://php.net/memory_limit))?

I have problems to find these informations in the [*System Requirements*](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html) despite the second release candidate has been already pushed out.

Comment: When a system with  2048M for memory_limit was reviewed, the comment from reviewers were "For vanilla Magento 1024M recommended". This is ca. Mid Oct 2015.

Answer (score 14):

The official system requirements (or rather: recommendations) are:

> Increase the PHP memory limit to at least **768MB** for normal operation or **2GB** for testing.

<sup>Source: Recommendations for [CentOS](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html) and [Ubuntu](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html)</sup>

I would only increase it to a higher value if you encounter problems where the memory limit is hit. Then debug and fix these problems, and set the memory limit back to normal when successful.

Comment: __My cron job doesn't work even I put memory limit to 768 MB__

Comment: So? What kind of answer do you expect to this?

Comment: I don't expect an answer on it, I just informed that cron doesn't run even with 768M. That's it. It may be useful for other people who read this page.

Comment: OK, sorry for the misunderstanding. But of course this depends on what the cron is doing. There might be extensions involved that need optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Actually `memory_limit` is totally up to you, you have to see how your application behaves. Do not be confused with big numbers. Any script must work as fast as possible and take not much than 3-4 times of its per process memory, which is 60MB x 4 = ~300MB an average. IMHO

768mb is just a precaution, so your server will not melt down or become unresponsive.

In some circumstances it may go beyond, so you have to debug these cases. configure your database and web stack.

Comment: PHP memory limit is configured per process. Also a lot of your answer sounds like speculation. And the first sentence is right only to the case that it's me who can configure it, but it's not up to me regardless the case that with let's say the configuration default of 128M Magento will refuse to work. Have you verified the concrete number 768M you give in the answer that it is working? On which specification is your calculation based, can you please reference it with a hyperlink and quote the underlying parts from it? How does it add to the given answer?

Comment: you just dont understand - it will work with default value, you can even set `-1` it is simply depends on your magento code and stack configuration. you must yourself come to this, to find the right limit.

Comment: I beg your pardon, but I have not asked about how to configure or change the PHP memory limit. I'm perfectly aware of it and how it works. I'm asking  about what the vendor of the Magento Commerce Version 2  software specifies as a memory limit. If you set to -1 for example but the system you've got  Magento 2 running on for example has only 128 MB that system would certainly not match the system requirements. Even though you set PHP memory limit to -1. The point in question here is the asking for reference. In your answer you don't give Magento 2 specific reference.

Comment: i gave you the explanation, this value is not constant or given exact up to a byte. anyway if you need to confirm system requirements you have to write to magento support.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 limits its memory usage to 768M in the main .htaccess file: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2335247d4ae2dc1e0728ee73022b0a244ccd7f4c/.htaccess#L40
This is the PHP-only limit for a single HTTP request. If your store need to serve 10 HTTP requests simultaneously then you need up to 10 * 768M = 7680M of memory for PHP interpreter only (in reality it is much lower because of cache usage, but there are some memory intensive tasks like compilation, reindexing, some 3rd-systems integrations which sometimes disable its memory limit at all and use a lot of memory).
Also you need some memory for other software environment: MySQL, web server, mail software, operating system, and so on.

Comment: _10 HTTP requests simultaneously then you need up to 10 * 768M = 7680M_   **WHOA**... what a Saturday morning... if your application ever takes that much memory, well, then i would not be so sure about the quality of your extensions...

Comment: have you ever read that manual??? http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit