# How long does your setup:upgrade script take?

Tags: magento2

We're running a system with ~140,000 products on some good server hardware and wondered how long other sites take to do some basic tasks.

The `magento setup:upgrade` command takes almost 6 hours for us to complete.

I believe this is to do with it looking at just about every file within the main directory checking for file permissions etc.

We're using an NFS system to store static media on a shared location to allow our load balancers to send requests to two different application servers.

Is our hardware setup wrong? Or is this just how long it takes?

Your setup information and time to run this command would be appreciated.

Comment: Mine is about 10 seconds

Comment: Thanks - and how many products (with images) do you have?

Comment: I'm not sure if it has an effect on this more indexing but store has about 500, i'm building another site which is going to have about 10,000 at the min so will let you know if it changes.

Comment: The time increase we found was in relation to the quantity of image files the script checked for file permissions (please see my answer below). As such, the more products, the more images (of various sizes), the more time it took to check those files' permissions. This quickly adds up with ~140k products, multiple images per product and multiple sizes per image.

Comment: Interesting yeah that is a lot of products never knew it did all the images aswell tho. That is such a long time have you sorted it then?

Comment: Not sorted, worked around! See my answer below for what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems that, as part of the `setup:upgrade`command, Magento likes to check every file within the server for permission errors.

This is triggered within `installDataFixtures()` with a call to `$this->checkInstallationFilePermissions();` within file `setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php`

I have circumvented this command, which now takes less than 10 seconds to complete the entire process whilst I submit a bug to the Git repository to see if they can re-engineer this check to something that is done less frequently.

Answer (score 1):

I can run this command in 12.5 seconds on my local, however I have server that it takes 5.5 minutes to run it on with the same code base and the same database...

Turns out NFS can play a huge roll in how long it takes to run.

Proven by going to where the NFS mount is from and running the same command.

When you go to the server

Comment: Yes, we also had media on NFS, but brought it back internally.

Answer (score 0):

`magento setup:upgrade` should not be affected by how many products you have.

How much is your PHP memory limit?

This is set in php.ini and should be at least 2 gigabytes:

```
memory_limit = 2048M
```

with more than a hundred modules it takes about a minute.

Here is Magento's official documentation on how to configure your servers:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html

Comment: Thanks. Our server technician isn't quite comfortable at leaving it at this level all the time. Would you leave it at 2G for production? Or just change it when required? Or do you have a more elaborate setup with a separate development server?

Comment: Yes, It would be like this on production (or more). As long as that's not all the RAM your server has. 
Development servers are usually kept with the same settings as production servers to make sure everything works fine. I just disable caches while developing.

Comment: If you are using a shared server, and you are not allowed to make changes, you can ask to increase the memory limit only when doing upgrades. see here:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90052/magento2-system-requirements-php-memory-limit

Comment: No, there's plenty of memory and it's private dedicated servers; so we have full control of the configuration. PHP on the CLI has memory set to -1 (e.g. unlimited), but it's still taking hours to complete. It seems to stop at "DDL cache cleared successfully". Any ideas what it is up to at that point?

Comment: No, I'm sorry I'm out of ideas. I hope somebody can help. :(