# How can I install Magento on Ubuntu 16.04 XAMPP with PHP version 7.1.1?

Tags: magento2, php-7, xampp, linux

I'm totally new to Magento. I'm trying to install Magento 2 Community Edition on my XAMPP on Ubuntu 16.04 that having PHP version 7.1.1.

It gives an error :

> PHP Version Check Your PHP version is 7.1.1. The required PHP version
>   is ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6. Hide detail Download and install PHP
>   from www.php.net using this PHP Documentation. For additional
>   assistance, contact your hosting provider.

Is there any way to install Magento with this configuration ?

**Edit :**
My question is regarding PHP version, and with current PHP version is it possible to install Magento, or I've to downgrade it. is my question ?

Any kind of help is Appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of magento 2 are you trying to install 2.1.x or 2.0.x ?

Comment: Magento-CE-2.1.5_sample_data-2017-02-20-05-07-23.zip

Comment: Actually I'm downloading this version for windows machine. Is it possible that it runs on Ubuntu/Linux, or I've to download tar.gz. Because it runs on Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento2 System Requirements PHP Memory Limit](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90052/magento2-system-requirements-php-memory-limit)

Comment: @MagenX My question is regarding PHP version, and with current PHP version is it possible to install Magento, or I've to downgrade it. is my question ?

Comment: @GaneshAher with your current PHP version no It is not possible !!! you must need to downgrade it  to at least 7.0.4 . You need to refer technology stack of magento 2

Comment: @Manthan Dave Yes, I'm now downgrading my XAMPP, and PHP.

Comment: i mean you have to use search. but obviously there is a link to magento 2 sys requirements

Comment: You can also use `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` to ignore the PHP version constraint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes The error shows correct . **Because Magento 2 won't support PHP version 7.1.1.**

**Both Magento 2.0.x and Magento 2.1.X both Support PHP 7 Version but with limited version Edition.**

Magento 2 compatible with PHP Version **7.0.x to 7.0.6** in that 7.0.2 and 7.0.4

So ultimately you need to **downgrade your PHP version 7.1.1 to At least 7.0.4**

Kindly check Technolgy stack requirements for **magento 2 below links are more helps to you :**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

**Update :**

To Downgrade Php version from 7.1.1 to Php version 7.0.4

Run below commands in sequence :

1) sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

2) sudo apt-get update

3) sudo apt-get remove php7.1.1

4) sudo apt-get install php7.0.4

5) sudo service php7.0-fpm restart

For more reference refer this link - https://askubuntu.com/questions/856793/upgrade-to-the-specific-php-7-1-from-php-7-0-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Please help me to downgrade PHP to 7.0.4. on Ubuntu 16.04 in XAMPP.

Comment: @GaneshAher sure i have updated the answer please check

Comment: Thanks, but is it work with XAMPP - PHP installation ? Because I've PHP with XAMPP, and not separately installed PHP.

Comment: @GaneshAher then simply downgrade your XAMPP server version by reinstalling it . you need to install it again which is compatible with php 7.0.x only

Comment: @GaneshAher Happy to help !! keep helping